# What replaces Subject.prototype.hasObservers

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs5

In RxJS version 4 there was the method hasObservers on Subjects which seems to have been removed and I am trying to migrate.  This method removal is not listed on the how to migrate page.

```
hasObservers: function () { checkDisposed(this); return this.observers.length > 0; }
```

What is another solution to get a boolean if a subject has a subscriber before next is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no analog for this function in rxjs 5. But you can add your own:

```js
Subject.prototype.hasObservers = function hasObservers() {
    if (this.closed) {
        throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
    }

    return this.observers.length > 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the source code how [`observers` array is defined](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L28) you'll see that it's a public property so you can access it directly:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

let s = new Subject();
s.subscribe(val => val);
s.subscribe(val => val);

console.log(s.observers.length > 0);
```

This prints `true`.

Comment: Note that `observers` equals `null` after `unsubscribe` is called on subject.